# .net Core 2.1.x EntityFramework | DatabaseGeneratedAttribute annotations could not be found

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to make use of .Net Entity Framework Core for my application. Relevant portions from .csproj files are:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.0" PrivateAssets="All"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.0"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.0"/>
```

In my entity classes I'm using the annotations as described in [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#data-annotations). However, my build is failing with errors like:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I have included necessary "using" statements in the code. Still the error seems to persist. Any pointers/suggestions what to check for in order to solve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

I'm developing using VS Code on macOS.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After a exploring the [API docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema(v=vs.110).aspx) for the annotations, I figured that one needs to include the following using statement:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

The tutorials of .NET Core Entity Framework that I was referring to seems to be misleading as it only had this "using" statement:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Hopefully this answer will help someone stuck with this issue.